# Do I need to tighten this EZSet door knob?

Tags: doorknob, front-door

My frond door has an EZSet door knob. (See photo with brand name.)

The knob is looser than in past years.  When I pull on it from the inside, it moves toward me about 1/8".  (See two photos below, with and without pulling.)  Is this enough of an issue that I should try to tighten the knob.  (I don't want it to fail unexpectedly.)

If the knob needs to be tightened, do I just tighten the exposed screws or remove the exposed screws and then pop off the cover and tighten the screws inside? (See photo
s showing exposed screws and tiny slot to pop off the cover.)

[image: Brand name]
[image: Pull to show 1/8" play]
[image: Knob without pulling on it]
[image: Screw and tiny gap]

Comment: Can try undoing the screws holding the knob and seeing if there is any way of tightening it up, but I think it has worn out and a new one is the only fix.

Comment: @crip659 Is it likely to fail, or get slowly worse?

Comment: There might be a way of tightening it inside, but if not the only answer is, yes, no, maybe.  Should only take a few minutes to take apart and see.  If no way to tighten, having a spare handy won't hurt.